# Unable to edit in SQL Server Management Studio via 'Edit top 200 Rows' as Geometry displayed as Well Known Text

Tags: sql-server, geometry, ssms

On two of my work machines I have suddenly no longer been able to 'edit top 200 rows' if the table has a geometry field. The geometry is converted to well known text and if I edit any field in this view I get the error:

> The parameter type "Internal.sys.geometry" is invalid. Parameter name: value.

Geometry fields appear fine with a normal select statement.

I installed the SSMS update with no luck. I am on version 18.12.

Comment: Have you logged a bug with MS?

Comment: I will do that now. Other users have the same issue, since Friday.